# I am a Swedish citizen planning to visit Cuba in a couple of months. Will I have any problem in getting a B1/B2 visa to USA after visiting Cuba?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, cuba

I have a B1/B2 US visa and I am planning to visit Cuba soon. Will I have any problem in renewing my US visa once it expires if I've been to Cuba? I know it's a problem to get an ESTA after visiting Cuba.

Comment: It's not a problem to get an ESTA, you simply no longer qualify for an ESTA.